# Can not create web project with Java EE 7 version , wildfly 9.0.1 and netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans, wildfly, netbeans-8

I Can not create web project with Java EE 7 version , wildfly 9.0.1 and netbeans 8.0.2 , The only available option is Java EE 6 . please check this print screen.

Not that I am able to create Java EE 7 project using wildfly 8.2
[image]

Comment: Yes, currently Netbeans 8.0.2 doesn't support WildFly 9 (it incorrectly identify it). You can use the 8.1 Beta1 which should be available soon or the nightly builds. I'm trying to backport the fix and upload the plugin in the plugin portal in the meanwhile

Comment: If you are courageous I've backported the changes from Netbeans 8.1 dev to http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53333/wildfly-application-server so that the plugin supports WF 9 and WF 9 Servlet

Comment: worked! @ehsavoie ,  I can start the app server but I can not close it., do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Does the deployment works ? I'm going to check

Comment: i created a simple application and it worked, but I as I told you I can not stop wildfly once its running

Comment: Which version of the plugin do you have ?

Comment: 1438783432_org-netbeans-modules-javaee-wildfly

Comment: Hum I mean the version in the plugins dialog. Something like : <br/>Installed version: 1.0.20<br/>Available version: 1.0.21 Author: Emmanuel Hugonnet (ehsavoie)<br/>Date: 8/11/15 Source: org-netbeans-modules-javaee-wildfly.nbm

Comment: I dont know how to get the version number now, but I am working with the latest .nbm file version that I downloaded in 6th of August 2015.

Comment: You have it in the plugin manager (where you install plugins) when you selected an installed plugin. I can't reproduce your issue with my development build of the plugin for 8.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Hum I mean the version in the plugins dialog.
Something like : 
Installed version: 1.0.20
Available version: 1.0.21
Author: Emmanuel Hugonnet (ehsavoie)
Date: 8/11/15 
Source: org-netbeans-modules-javaee-wildfly.nbm